# How to tell what an object extends externally in java

Tags: java, inheritance, object, extend

Hello I need to know if there is a way to find out what an object extends in Java.

```
public void function(Obj obj)
{
    // ...
```

Is there a way to find out what obj extends? or if it extends anything?

Comment: Do you mean `Object` as in the ultra-super-granddaddy of all objects, or a generic, some other `Object` in the sense that you don't know where it came from?

Comment: if you need to know what is the type of your object then there is a high chance that your design is wrong. OOP is about using polymorphism instead of `if (type = ... ) then ... else ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want to find out which class this object is an instance of. In this case you can simply use `Object.getClass()`. Also you have `Class.getSuperclass()` at your disposal if you need to find the superclasses of the object class.

Answer (score 2):

## Finding super class:

```
YourClass.class.getSuperclass()
```

or (when having an instance of `YourClass`):

```
yourClass.getClass().getSuperclass()
```

## Finding which interfaces are implemented by given class/object

```
YourClass.class.getInterfaces()
```

or (same as above):

```
yourClass.getClass().getInterfaces()
```

Comment: Do you mean `yourObject.getClass()`? Wouldn't `yourClass.getClass()` always return the `Class` instance for the `Class` class? Say that three times fast!

Comment: @DavidHarkness: `YourClass` is `class` name while `yourClass` is an instance of `YourClass` (mind naming). I will clarify it. +1 for the last sentence ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Object is the absolute "super class" of all classes in Java. Object does not extend any other class.